# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on getChildByTag on onExit method

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to stop all action of the `ccSprite` on `onExit` method and Following is my code.

```
-(void)onExit{
    CCSprite *still_water_flare1;
    for(NSInteger i=1;i<=50;i++)
    {
        still_water_flare1  = (CCSprite*)[water_trip getChildByTag:i];
        [still_water_flare1 stopAllActions];

    }

    [[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:nil];
    [super onExit];
}
```

But it's giving me **EXC_BAD_ACCESS** on  `still_water_flare1  = (CCSprite*)[water_trip getChildByTag:i];` this line. `getChildByTag`. I have also used same code at other place and its works fine. But It's only not working in onExit method. How to stop all action of `ccSprite` on onExit method?

Comment: onExit means the node will be leaving its parent. Unless you're going to keep self in memory, self's child nodes and their actions will end. If you're not intentionally keeping self in memory, you have a memory leak. Try enabling zombie objects.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Actully I am new in cocos2d.. How can I stop all action for above sprite ??